# Auto populate Combobox ExtJS

Tags: forms, extjs, combobox

I have comboboxes that have predefined values in a form. It works well, however when the user submits the form and I do a reset using:

```
    this.getView().getForm().reset()
```

This resets the form perfectly in most areas, and the comboboxes get repopulated with the predefined value again, however, if you leave the values as is in the new form and submit again, you will receive a **"Cannot read property '0' of null"** error

How I am prepopulating the values:

```
       xtype: 'combobox',
        fieldLabel: '<span style="color: red; font-weight: bold;">*</span> <span style="font-weight: bold;">Are there any injuries or Fatalities?<span>',
        id: 'injuriesFatalities',
        labelWidth: 400,
        labelAlign: 'right',
        allowBlank: false,
        displayField: 'name',
        value: 'No',
        store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            fields: ['name'],
            data: [{ name: 'No' }, { name: 'Yes' }]
        })
```

What the user currently is required to do to avoid this error is reselect what is currently selected in the combobox. I feel I can avoid this problem if I get one of the following questions answered:

A) How do I properly make the predefined combobox value, or

B) how do I properly clear a form with out getting this error?

***SYNOPSIS***

**Goal:**

1. Need to clear form (form currently clears)
2. Need to prepopulate combobox's values (form currently populates visible combobox)

**Problem:**

-combobox's do not actually hold the proper values even when the combobox selects the value after the form is reset.

**Error thrown:**

"Cannot read property '0' of null"

Answer (score 2):

You are missing **valueField** config in combobox config. Also you will need to specify the specified valuefield in your data.
You can always reuse same fields but its a good practice to keep displayField and valueField as different keys so that they can be identified easily.

Here is an example on how to do it:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        var store = Ext.create("Ext.data.Store", {
            fields: ['name', 'age'],
            data: [{
                name: 'Test1',
                age: 22,
                value: 'test1'
            }, {
                name: 'Test2',
                age: 23,
                value: 'test2',
            }, {
                name: 'Test3',
                age: 24,
                value: 'test3'
            }]
        });

        Ext.Viewport.add({
            xtype: 'panel',
            layout: 'fit',
            title: 'Form Exmaple',
            items: [{
                xtype: 'formpanel',
                id: 'formId',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'combobox',
                    store: store,
                    displayField: 'name',
                    valueField: 'value',
                    value: 'test2'
                }],
                buttons: [{
                    text: 'Reset',
                    handler: function(me) {
                        var form = Ext.getCmp('formId');
                        form.reset();
                    }
                }]
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

**Example Fiddle:** https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2a2t

Comment: Thanks for your help, it was an additional issue on how I was selecting the id. I was using:    damages.lastSelectedRecords[0].id; and I needed to do damages.valueCollection.items[0].id